# C API to return timestring in specified time zone?

Tags: c, timezone

In C, there is any API which converts time returned by `time()` function to a specific timezone?
There is a function `strftime()` which converts into current timezone of the system.
But what I want is function input is time (returned by `time()`) and timeZone and it will convert the specific formatted time in said timezone format.

Is there such an API?

Comment: does `localtime` , `strftime`  not help ?

Comment: @keety: `localtime()` plus `strftime()` do not help if your current time zone is, say, IST (UTC+5:30) but you want the time printed in EST (US/Eastern or UTC-5:00).

Answer (score 7):

POSIX specifies [`tzset()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tzset.html):

> The `tzset()` function shall use the value of the environment variable TZ to set time conversion information used by `ctime`, `localtime`, `mktime`, and `strftime`. If TZ is absent from the environment, implementation-defined default timezone information shall be used.

So, you could in theory use something like this to convert `t0` (a `time_t`) into US/Eastern time when that is not your default TZ:

```
char old_tz[64];
strcpy(old_tz, getenv("TZ"));
setenv("TZ", "EST5", 1);
tzset();
struct tm *lt = localtime(&t0);
char buffer[64];
strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", lt);
setenv("TZ", old_tz, 1);
tzset();
```

This preserves a copy of the old time zone (you can't rely on it not changing or going out of scope while you're dinking with this stuff), then sets the target time zone in the environment.  It then tells the system to look at $TZ and set the local time zone accordingly.  You then convert the given `time_t` value to a broken down local time with `localtime()`, format the string, then reset the TZ environment variable and tell the system to take another look at it with `tzset()` again.

In practice, this may or may not work; it depends on the system.

If you need thread-safe versions of this stuff, you'll have to work harder.  This is categorically not thread-safe as written.

The sample code has skimped on error checking — it doesn't have any.

I would never claim this is a simple way of doing it; there ought to be a better way.

#### Test Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void time_convert(time_t t0, char const *tz_value)
{
    char old_tz[64];
    strcpy(old_tz, getenv("TZ"));
    setenv("TZ", tz_value, 1);
    tzset();
    char new_tz[64];
    strcpy(new_tz, getenv("TZ"));
    char buffer[64];
    struct tm *lt = localtime(&t0);
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", lt);
    setenv("TZ", old_tz, 1);
    tzset();
    printf("%ld = %s (TZ=%s)\n", (long)t0, buffer, new_tz);
}

int main(void)
{
    time_t t0 = time(0);
    char *tz = getenv("TZ");
    time_convert(t0, tz);
    time_convert(t0, "UTC0");
    time_convert(t0, "IST-5:30");
    time_convert(t0, "EST5");
    time_convert(t0, "EST5EDT");
    time_convert(t0, "PST8");
    time_convert(t0, "PST8PDT");
}
```

#### Test Output

```
1335761328 = 2012-04-29 23:48:48 (TZ=CST6CDT)
1335761328 = 2012-04-30 04:48:48 (TZ=UTC0)
1335761328 = 2012-04-30 10:18:48 (TZ=IST-5:30)
1335761328 = 2012-04-29 23:48:48 (TZ=EST5)
1335761328 = 2012-04-30 00:48:48 (TZ=EST5EDT)
1335761328 = 2012-04-29 20:48:48 (TZ=PST8)
1335761328 = 2012-04-29 21:48:48 (TZ=PST8PDT)
```

Note that when the strings for EST and PST do not have a daylight saving code specified, you get one time zone offset; when there is a daylight saving code set (such as `"EST5EDT"` or `"PST8PDT"`) and the time to be printed is at the appropriate time of year (such as end of April), you get the EDT or PDT time value printed.

Note, too, that there are conflicting ISO standards on how to handle time zones.  ISO 8601 (for date/time formatting) says that time zones east of UTC (Greenwich) are positive and those west of UTC are negative.  At least some other standards (e.g. SQL, ISO 9075) use the same notation.  On the other hand, POSIX (aka ISO 9945) uses the opposite convention in TZ, as shown in the example code.  The conflict is accepted only because of long-standing precedent.  The C standard is silent on the format (or existence) of the TZ environment variable (though C99 §7.23.3.5 *The `strftime` function* does reference ISO 8601 a number of times).

And (just as a salutary reminder why error checking is a good idea), on Mac OS X 10.7.3, my environment doesn't have TZ set in it (but it is normally US/Pacific, aka Cupertino, aka America/Los_Angeles, time).  So the code above crashes when `getenv()` returns a null pointer.  I ran it with `TZ=CST6CDT` in the environment, as you can see from the first line of output.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for your detailed reply. I got the idea, I need to have it thread-safe logic. I will work on this.

Comment: The time APIs are not thread-safe, period. Well, `strftime()` is OK, but the `localtime()` and `gmtime()` functions typically return a pointer to the same piece of storage, for example, so you have to capture the result before another thread calls it.  That's why the `localtime_r()` and `gmtime_r()` interfaces are defined in POSIX.  However, setting the environment is not thread-safe, and the design of `tzset()` is not thread-safe and therefore this whole mechanism is not thread-safe.  The standard API is bad (I'm tempted to claim 'appalling'!) because it doesn't tackle this issue.

Comment: Well, the time API is really old, from way before we had threads. However, it can easily be done by having a function that uses uses a lock to prevent any other thread from running that one function. However, that lock needs to be used for any time function used anywhere in the application. Good luck with that!

Comment: Btw, the `strcpy(buf, getenv("TZ"))` will crash (SEGV) if TZ is not defined in your environment.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: Yes, the time API is old, and yes, the code will crash if `TZ` is not defined in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

There are really three steps to look at here. First, a `time_t` represents an absolute time stamp -- something at least conceptually on the order of a UTC timestamp. It's not (normally) in any particular time zone -- it typically represents the number of seconds since some epoch (often midnight January 1, 1970).

You can convert that to a `struct tm`, which breaks that time stamp out into an actual date and time -- a year, month, day, hour, minute, and second. There are two functions to do that conversion: `gmtime`, which leaves it as a UTC-style time (i.e., in the Greenwich time zone). The other is `localtime`, which converts it to whatever time zone the environment has been configured to believe represents the location of the machine.

The next step is to use `strftime` to convert that to something readable. This is based on the current locale, so (for example) as I write this it's what I think of as "Sunday". If my machine was configured for Spanish, however, that would probably show up as "Domingo", or something on that order.

You really have two rather different questions. You can only convert a `time_t` into a time for one of two time zones: the "local" time zone (at least, whatever the machine has been configured to think of a "local"), or Greenwich time. If you want any other time zone, you're pretty much stuck with something like converting to GM time, then adjusting to the timezone of your choice.

There is more provision for adjusting formatting. By default the library will always convert for the "C" locale, which is pretty much a simplified version of US English. You can also set the nameless locale ("") which gives you a locale that's suppose to match how the machine has been configured. As a third alternative, most libraries will let you specify a name for a specific locale, so if you wanted your date formatted as somebody in the French-speaking part of Canada would expect, you'd set the locale to something like "French_Canada" and that's what you'd get (though the string you use varies with the standard library, so you might need to use something like "fr-can" instead).