# C API to get start and end date of DST using tz database

Tags: c, linux, timezone, dst, c-api

I want to print the start and end date of DST when the tz data is given using a C code.

I know that I can use `getenv` to read the TZ variable. When I use this I get the local time/required time of the zone. But I want to get the DST Start and End date for the given tz database

I referred to this API: [C API to return timestring in specified time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378093/c-api-to-return-timestring-in-specified-time-zone)

It gives the local time of the specified time zone, but I want an API to display the DST start and end date for the given tz info.

Can anyone please help me on this. I want to use TZ environment variable to get the start and end of DST in a particular region directly fom the system

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using linux